# Internet Explorer 11 Developer Tools: 'DOM refresh' button is missing

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm running the [IE11 on Win81](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) VM image provided by Microsoft.

The problem I'm having is that the Developer Tools' DOM Explorer tab only shows the state of the document after the page loads. Any dynamic elements added by JavaScript aren't shown. This makes it hard to debug my app.

Now, I thought that this view used to have a "refresh" button that synced the DOM Explorer view with the actual document, allowing you to inspect the current state of the page.

But I simply can't find the button. It doesn't appear on the toolbar (see below):

[image: Image showing the Developer Tools, DOM explorer tab of IE11]

This is the IE version that I'm running:

[image: IE11 version dialog]

Comment: I remember there's no such "refresh" button in DOM Explorer tab. I don't find it on my IE 11 version 11.630.19041.0. You can try to clear IE cache and try again. If it still doesn't work, there might be something wrong with your F12 dev tools. You can try to reinstall IE or install the latest updates of Windows to update IE.

Comment: Huh. Maybe the "DOM refresh" button never existed and I just dreamed it.

Comment: The DOM refresh button is rumoured to have existed in previous versions of IE.. there's documentation floating around the Internet about it (two blue arrows in a kind of circle).  I don't see it on IE11 anywhere either.